# How to find the longitudinal waves in an elastic bar hanging from the ceiling?

Tags: waves, stress-strain

The vertical displacements $w(y)$ in a bar hanging from a fixed point, due to its own weight, compared with the unstressed configuration follow a quadratic equation, that solves: $$E\frac{\partial^2 w}{\partial y^2} = \mu g$$

Now the dynamic case, supposing a negligible dumping, and only vertical dispacements. The bar is supported from below, fixed in the ceiling, and suddenly the support is removed. I came to a non homogeneous wave equation:$$\mu \frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial t^2} - E\frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial y^2} = -\mu g$$

Is it necessary to use Green function for a case like that, where the RHS is just a constant function?

My idea was to solve it by setting a new variable $u-w$, where $w(y)$ is the solution of the static situation, and solving the homogeneous wave equation for $u-w$.

In order to fulfill the boundary condition of $u(0) = w(0) = 0$ for any $t$, I believe that the solution should be a stationary wave. The values of $t$ for which $u-w=0$ all along the bar corresponds to the static equilibrium.

(The similar questions that I've found in the site refer to transversal displacements in a rope. I am interested in longitudinal displacements in a bar.)

Comment: I think that the source term should be something like $\mu g (L - y)$ since the lower the material point is the lesser the pulling force it sees.  Also, is your question how to solve this differential equation?

Comment: @nicoguaro The static solution is easy. The dynamical non homogeneous equation is the issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$\mu \frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial t^2} - E\frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial y^2} = -\mu g$$

> Is it necessary to use Green function for a case like that, where the
> RHS is just a constant function?

No, it is not and it is not necessary for simple functions on the RHS either.

(But note that I make *no pronouncements re. the validity of your PDE and that you have not provided any initial/boundary conditions*)

So we're looking for a function $u(y,t)$ that satisfies (and its initial/boundary conditions)

$$\mu u_{tt}-Eu_{yy}=-\mu g\tag{1}$$

To do so we assume that $u(y,t)$ can be written as

$$u(y,t)=u_E(y)+v(y,t)\tag{2}$$

Here $u_E(y)$ is the solution to

$$-E\frac{\mathrm{d}^2u_E}{\mathrm{d}y^2}=-\mu g\tag{3}$$

(we can ditch the partials because it has become an ordinary DE in $(u,y)$  only)

$u_E(y)$ is often called the *steady state solution*. $(3)$ easily solves to

$$u_E(y)=\frac{\mu g}{2E}y^2+C_1 y+C_2$$

The integration constants $C_1$ and $C_2$ need to be determined from the PDE's boundary conditions (but were not provided).

This way, the steady state solution $u_E(y)$ fully satisfies $(1)$.

It follows that there must, by virtue of the **Superposition Principle**, exist a function $v(y,t)$ so that it and $u_E(y)$ satisfies $(1)$.

To check this, insert

$$u(y,t)=\frac{\mu g}{2E}y^2+C_1 y+C_2+v(y,t)$$

into (1). You will obtain a **homogeneous** PDE in $v(y,t)$.

Solve this PDE and add the result to $u_E(y)$ for t**he full solution of $u(y,t)$.**

---

So let's determine $C_1$ and $C_2$, as per the OP's BC (comment section):

$$u_E(y)=\frac{\mu g}{2E}y^2+C_1 y+C_2$$
$$u(0,t)=0\Rightarrow u_E(0)=0$$
$$u_y(L,t)=0\Rightarrow u'_E(L)=0$$
Obviously $C_2=0$.

Now:

$$u'_E(y)=\frac{\mu g}{E}y+C_1$$
$$0=\frac{\mu gL}{E}+C_1$$
$$C_1=-\frac{\mu gL}{E}$$
$$u_E(y)=\frac{\mu g}{E}\left(\frac{y}{2}-L\right)y$$
Going back to $(1)$:
$$\mu u_{tt}-Eu_{yy}=-\mu g\tag{1}$$

And:

$$u(y,t)=\frac{\mu g}{E}\left(\frac{y}{2}-L\right)y+v(y,t)$$
Calculate the partial derivatives:
$$u_{tt}=v_{tt}\tag{4}$$
$$u_{yy}=\frac{\mu g}{E}+v_{yy}\tag{5}$$
Inserting both into $(1)$ yields:
$$v_{tt}=\frac{E}{\mu}v_{yy}$$
which is the classic wave equation, **homogeneous**.

It is a linear, second order PDE that can be solved by Separation of Variables. *I'll leave that part of the derivation to you*.

You'll also need an initial condition $(t=0)$:

$$u(y,0)=f(y)$$

[An example of solving the Wave Equation can be found here](http://www.sciencemadness.org/talk/viewthread.php?tid=65532&page=17#pid451284) (own work).

Comment: It would be interesting to see this finished off, with sensible boundary conditions that you choose or the OP suggests, to get a position for each part of the bar as a function of y and time.

Comment: @JohnHunter   If the OP presents the correct BCs and IC, I'd be glad to follow through.

Comment: @Gert well, the BC for the static solution are: w(0)=0 because the bar is fixed on its top end, and $\frac{\partial w}{\partial y} = 0$ at the bottom $(y=L)$ because the stress is zero there. For the dynamical solution $u(0,t)=0$ for sure. That is why I think that only a stationary wave can be a solution.

Comment: @ClaudioSaspinski I'll use these and see where that leads us. Ta.

Comment: @ClaudioSaspinski So it is definitely possible to sole your original PDE w/o Green's function. I've left the last leg to you.

Comment: Thank you. It confirms the idea that I have about, but it is more clear now. In the formula for the static solution, I think there is a L instead of 1 between the parentheses.

Comment: @ClaudioSaspinski Yes, correct. Edited. Good close reading!

Answer (score 0):

If the Youngs modulus is $E$, Area of bar is $A$, tension or force in the bar is $F$, extension is $x$ and length is $L$

$E = \frac{FL}{xA}$

then

$$x = \frac{FL}{EA} \tag 1$$

and if it reached equilibrium after removal of the support, at extension $x_0$

$$x_o = \frac{mgL}{EA}\tag 2$$

We could consider the restoring force acting on the rest of the bar a short distance below the point of attachment.

$$F_R=mg-x\left(\frac{EA}{L}\right)\tag 3$$

using (2) in (3) and dividing by $m$

$$a=g - \frac{xg}{x_0}\tag 4$$

It's simple harmonic motion around equilibrium position $x_0$, so if we let $x=x_0 + dx$

$$a=g\left(1-\frac{x_0+dx}{x_0}\right)=  - g\frac{dx}{x_o}\tag5$$

an acceleration of the extension proportional to extension.

substituting from (2) for $x_0$

$$a=-\frac{EA}{Lm} \delta x \tag 6$$

and defining $$\omega^2 = \frac{EA}{Lm}\tag 7$$

for the bottom of the bar, the angular frequency for the S.H.M is $\omega$

$x_0  = \frac{g}{\omega^2}$, so

$$x=\frac{g}{\omega^2}\sin (\omega t)\tag 8$$

where time is measured from when the bottom of the bar passes through the equilibrium position

for other points on the bar, the amplitude would be changed by a factor $\frac{y}{L}$, where $y$ is the original distance down the bar and since the different points on the bar perform SHM with different starting points
$$w(y,t) = y +\frac{y}{L} \left( \frac{g}{\omega^2}+\frac{g}{\omega^2}\sin (\omega t)\right) \tag{9}$$

Here $w(y,t)$ is the distance from the support, of a point originally at $y$, at a time $t$ after passing through the equilibrium position.  If the displacement from the original position is required, just subtract the $y$.

Comment: I understood that $x$ is the vertical displacement, not the position (that is $y$ according to the last equation). In this case $x = x(y)$. But $x_0$ is called a (equilibrium) position, not a displacement.

Comment: If the bar was supported originally (and not got any extension) and then the support removed, and it was lowered gradually and left to hang unsupported, $x_0$ is how far the bottom of the bar would be from the starting position

Comment: ...so to summarise, $x$ is extension, $x_0$ is mean extension, $y$ is the original distance down the un-extended bar, $w(y,t)$ is the distance from the support of a point originally at $y$ at time $t$

Comment: Assuming that in $(5)$ $dx$ is $\mathrm{d}x$ (the differential), then $a=- g\frac{\mathrm{d}x}{x_o}$ is NOT the equation of motion of an SHO. $\ddot{x}=-\omega^2 x$ would be.

Comment: Your equation $(4)$ , slightly rewritten as $\ddot{x}+\frac{g}{x_0}x=g$ is also an DE of the SHO.

Comment: @Gert, the dx is the amount of extension from the equilibrium position (like an x) and because one end of the bar is fixed the acceleration of the other end is $\ddot{x}$, so the equation is equivalent to  $\ddot{x}=-\omega^2 x$.

Comment: @JohnHunter your equation (2) supposes the force $mg$ concentrated at the bottom of the bar. And equation (1) can be rearranged as: $\frac{x}{L} = \frac{F}{EA}$. It is also only valid for the bottom of the bar, and if $F$ is concentrated there. The corrected equation should be:  $\frac{x}{y} = \frac{F(y)}{EA}$. $F(y)$ is the weight below y, or $\mu A(L - y)g$.

Comment: All the weight $mg$ is supported at the top of the bar, i.e the tension there equals $mg$.  The $y$ in the equations in the answer is measured from the top of the bar downwards, i.e $y=0$ at the top, and $y=L$ at the bottom (before release).  The extension is $x$ and since the top is fixed $x$ is equivalent to the movement of the bottom of the bar, i.e if the bottom moves by $dx$ the extension of the bar is $dx$.  You've got me wondering whether $\omega^2$ should be a factor 2 different, but apart from that it seems ok, perhaps you can see what other answers you get, then choose.